# Big Commerce API - Leading zero in SKU is trimmed

Tags: bigcommerce

When creating items in Big Commerce from the API, if sku provided is a string of numbers and if there are leading zeroes, the leading zeroes will be trimmed. For example sku "01234" will become "1234".

```
    <skus>
      <sku>01234</sku>
      <upc>01234</upc>
      <cost_price>17.9800</cost_price>
      <inventory_level>1</inventory_level>
      <options>
        <option>
          <product_option_id>4778</product_option_id>
          <option_value_id>2113</option_value_id>
        </option>
      </options>
    </skus>
```

I was wondering if anyone has encountered this before and managed to do some work-around. Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Received response from Big Commerce, it is a bug if request is sent in XML format. In json it works fine. This will be soon fixed on their end.